# Setting groovy getter/setter methods via constructor in grails domain class

Tags: grails, groovy, constructor, javabeans

I have a grails unit test that has code similar to below and is appears that setting fields via getter/setter methods doesn't work with constructors (even though it actually works with non-domain classes).

I understand that the following works with properties:

```
class Person {
  def firstName
  def lastName

  def getFullName() {
    return "$firstName $lastName"
  }

  def setFullName(name) {
    firstName = name.split(" ")[0]
    lastName = name.split(" ")[1]
  }
}

def = new Person(fisrtName: "Joe", lastName: "Bloggs")
```

But when I do the following the first and last name fields don't get set:

```
def = new Person(fullName: "Joe Bloggs")
```

Is there a way to set fields via methods in a groovy contstructor?

Answer (score 3):

What version of groovy are you using?  This works fine for me with groovy 1.8.6 and I think it's worked for that way for a very long time:

```
class Person {
  def firstName
  def lastName

  def getFullName() {
    return "$firstName $lastName"
  }

  def setFullName(name) {
    firstName = name.split(" ")[0]
    lastName = name.split(" ")[1]
  }
}

def p1 = new Person(firstName: "Joe", lastName: "Bloggs")
def p2 = new Person(fullName: "Joe Bloggs")

assert p1.firstName == p2.firstName
assert p1.lastName == p2.lastName
```

Updated:

Just tried this on grails 2.0.3.  You need to be more explicit in your method signatures for grails to work.  I changed the method signature for the getter to be `String` and the setter to be `void` and it worked.  It did not work with just `def`.  Grails 2 is much more strict about matching signatures than previous versions of grails were and I'm betting that this is part of it.

Also, you should specify that the `fullName` "property" is transient as it isn't a real property that should get persisted in the database.  Here's the domain and test class that work for me in grails 2.0.3:

Person.groovy:

```
package com.example

class Person {
    String firstName
    String lastName

    static transients = ["fullName"]

    String getFullName() {
        return "$firstName $lastName"
    }

    void setFullName(String name) {
        firstName = name.split(" ")[0]
        lastName = name.split(" ")[1]
    }
}
```

PersonTests.groovy:

```
package com.example



import grails.test.mixin.*
import org.junit.*

/**
 * See the API for {@link grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin} for usage instructions
 */
@TestFor(Person)
@Mock([Person])
class PersonTests {

    void testFullName() {
        Person p1 = new Person(firstName: "Joe", lastName: "Bloggs").save(failOnError: true)
        Person p2 = new Person(fullName: "Joe Bloggs").save(failOnError: true)

        assert p1.firstName == p2.firstName
        assert p1.lastName == p2.lastName
        assert p1.fullName == p2.fullName
    }
}
```

Comment: You are correct.  This does work in groovy, I think where it fails for me is grails framework.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by [because](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8972)
See 'bindable' [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.2/ref/Constraints/bindable.html)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.